# Donation Script Trial

Tags: php, donations

I downloaded this [Donation Script](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/)

which I would like to use to enable visitor "Support" on a website.

I installed the mySql database edited the connect.php and FTP'ed the script files to a trial webspace but I cannot get any further. When I browse to the location I get messages like *The Web server is configured not to display a list of the contents of this directory*

I note that the downloaded script does not have a index.php script. How would I get a index.php script going to make the Donation Script work in my trial webspace?

Comment: Can you not access the script via `/donate.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just visit the demo. You need to append donate.php, just like they do.

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/donate.php

Comment: Thanks guys that got me going. I have a smilie face again. Good work.

Comment: @user1015361: Don't forget to evaluate and accept the good answers! :)